# Is it possible to have a multi-line log in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm sending logs to an nginx server and want to dump these logs to a file. When sending one log at a time, I was able to do this using the NginxEchoModule to force nginx to read the body like so:

```
http {
    log_format log_dump '$request_body';
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        access_log /logs/dump log_dump;
        location /logs {
            echo_read_request_body;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when I send one log at a time:

```
POST /logs HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

123456 index.html was accessed by 127.0.0.1

POST /logs HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

123457 favicon.ico was accessed by 127.0.0.1
```

However when I try to batch logs (to avoid both connection overhead and HTTP header overhead):

```
POST /logs HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

123456 index.html was accessed by 127.0.0.1
123457 favicon.ico was accessed by 127.0.0.1
```

This is what shows up in my log file:

```
123456 index.html was accessed by 127.0.0.1\x0A123457 favicon.ico was accessed by 127.0.0.1
```

Now my assumption is that because one nginx log line is intended to be ***one line***, it's encoding my new-line characters to ensure this. Is there a way to allow multi-line nginx logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually got the answer from one of the more experienced engineers at my work this time:

```
log_format log_dump escape=none '$request_body';
```

[This requires nginx version 1.13.10](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format), but prevents nginx from escaping new-lines in the logs:

```
$> curl http://localhost/logs -d "Words
dquote> More words"
$> cat /logs/dump
Words
More words
$>
```